# Chrome and probably Opera sort object properties automatically

Tags: javascript

Problem is: Chrome automatically sorts properties of object.

If I have an object like:

```
var obj = {4: "first", 2: "second", 1: "third"};
```

then when I do next:

```
for(var i in obj) {
    console.debug(obj[i]);
}
```

I see next:

`third`
`second`
`first`

but expect:

`first`
`second`
`third`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting javascript by property value ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-by-property-value)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Never rely on the order of properties. They are unordered and there is no specification that defines in which order properties should be enumerated.

[Chrome orders properties with numeric keys numerically](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164), whereas other browsers enumerate them in insertion order. It is implementation dependent.

Comment: `there is no specification that defines in which order properties should be enumerated` ..... I have an idea. How about the order WE PUT THEM IN.

Answer (score 5):

You should not expect any particular order for keys in `for..in` loops.  From [the MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order

If you want ordering using numerical keys, use an array.